# Change div content multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

Let's assume I have some text and I want this text to change languages whenever someone clicks the button with the desired language

I have been trying to get this function to work for more than 2 cases 
https://jsfiddle.net/scriv/1j0tm32k/25/

```js
(function() {
    const englishButton = document.getElementById('english');
    const greekButton = document.getElementById('greek');
    const translate = (lang) => {
        const textArea = document.getElementById('left');

        if (lang === 'english') {
            textArea.innerHTML = 'Text original in english';
        } else if (lang === 'greek') {
            textArea.innerHTML = 'same in greek';
        }
    }
    const handleEvent = function() {
        translate(this.id);
    };

    englishButton.addEventListener('click', handleEvent);
    greekButton.addEventListener('click', handleEvent);
})();
```

https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-contributing-to-open-source
Scroll down to geography and u will see that the content changes when these buttons are clicked below geography I want this for languages but I can't tell from inspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is working fine. `S` in spanish is in uppercase in DOM but it was in lowercase in JS. And, the comparisons should be `===` not `!==` unless you're trying to do something that I don't understand.
Fixed those 2 things here:

HTML:

```
<button id="english" class="one">
  English
</button>
<button id="greek" class="two">
  Ελληνικα
</button>
<button id="spanish" class="tres">
 Spanish
</button>

<div class="left" id="left">Text original in english</div>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
  const englishButton = document.getElementById('english');
  const greekButton = document.getElementById('greek');
  const EspButton = document.getElementById('spanish');
  const translate = (lang) => {
    const textArea = document.getElementById('left');

    if (lang === 'english') {
      textArea.innerHTML = 'Text original in english';
    } else if (lang === 'greek') {
      textArea.innerHTML = 'same in greek';
    } else if (lang === 'spanish') {
      textArea.innerHTML = "spanish";
    }
  }
  const handleEvent = function() {
    translate(this.id);
  };

  englishButton.addEventListener('click', handleEvent);
  greekButton.addEventListener('click', handleEvent);
  EspButton.addEventListener('click', handleEvent);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<button id="english" data-language="english" class="one">English</button>
<button id="greek" data-language="greek" class="two">Ελληνικα</button>
<button id="spanish" data-language="spanish" class="tres">Spanish</button>
<div class="left" id="left">Text original in english</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function () {
  const englishButton = document.getElementById('english');
  const greekButton = document.getElementById('greek');
  const espButton = document.getElementById('spanish');

  const translate = (lang) => {
    const textArea = document.getElementById('left');

    if (lang === 'greek') {
      textArea.innerHTML = 'Text original in greek';
    } else if (lang === 'english') {
      textArea.innerHTML = 'Text original in english';
    } else if (lang === 'spanish') {
        textArea.innerHTML = "Text original in spanish";
    }
  }

  const handleEvent = function () {
    translate(this.dataset.language);
    alert(this.dataset.language);
  };

  englishButton.addEventListener('click', handleEvent);
  greekButton.addEventListener('click', handleEvent);
  espButton.addEventListener('click', handleEvent);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be better using switch than multiple `if else`

Something like

```
switch (lang) {
  case 'greek' : textArea.innerHTML = 'Text original in greek';
  break;
  case 'spanish' : textArea.innerHTML = 'Text original in spanish';
  break;
  default : textArea.innerHTML = 'Text original in english';
}
```